# SignalR code not working in the ASP.NET mvc partial file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have the following code in my ASP.NET partial file:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><label id="message">No messages</label></li>
<li><input type="button" id="startButton" value="Start Monitoring" /></li> <!--Just for testing actual app won't have a button! -->
```

```
@section scripts {
<!--Script references. -->
<!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.2.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->
<script>

    $(function () {
        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
        var testHub = $.connection.testHub;

        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        testHub.client.displayMessages = function (message) {
            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#message').text(message);
        };

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#startButton').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                testHub.server.listenToMessages(1);
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

}

The ASP.NET partial file is referred in the _Layout.cshtml file to show on the top where the _loginPartial.cshtml used to be there in the template.

The problem is the Hub code is not hit when I press the startbutton. The same code when I place in the Index.html, it works. I have the JQuery added at the top in the layout file like below:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Any idea why I the partial file wont start the hub? The idea is I want to have the messages to show on the top for the user no matter which view he is at. That's why I want to use the partial file be placed in the Layout file.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

_Layout.html header looks like below:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
</head>
```

I changed my _LoginPartial as below:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Hello !", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "message", title = "Manage" })
    </li>
</ul>
<script>

    $(function () {
        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
        var testHub = $.connection.testHub;

        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        testHub.client.displayMessage = function (message) {
            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#message').text(message);
        };

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            testHub.server.hello();
        });
    });

</script>
```